# Full image is not showing in the background

Tags: html, css, next.js

I have a image which I want to completely show as background image .
[image]

As you can see in the below image , the girl & the dog is not completely shown:

*original image*
[image]

Is there any css property to completely so the image as the background ? or I have to resize the image ?

Here's my css:

```
*{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
}
body{
      background-image: url('../public/images/bg0.jpg');
      height: 100vh;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      object-fit: contain;
      transition: background-image 1.5s linear;
}
#__next{
      height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Since you've tagged this as [tag:next.js], are you using the `next/image` component to render the image? If so, could you also provide that code?

Answer (score 1):

You are using  `background-size: cover;` so the image will try to fit itself to the element.
You may change properties to  `background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;`.

or

using `background-position: bottom`.

I hope this solve your problem.

Check this W3 out [background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain) [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Using "background-size: cover;" the browser will expand the background photo so it will cover the whole website body. You could use "background-size: contain;" to see the whole image, but it will not cover the whole website. The best solution is to resize the image.